# Inserting values when identity is on

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012

I have a table with identity(1,1) field and i want to use insert into to insert values into it.
How can I insert values into the indentity field?
Thank you!

Comment: I don't know why Manu decided to edit this to be a question about [tag:mysql]. Their stated edit reason was "nothing to do with visual studio, must be mysql" but I'm not sure I follow that line of reasoning. If I had to guess at any database system, the mention of VS and the use of `IDENTITY(1,1)` would strongly suggest [tag:sql-server]. But it would help if the OP were to edit their question, remove the [tag:visual-studio-2012] and explicitly add the correct database system tag themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl ON
-- insert (include the ID column)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

you've got to do this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableNameHere ON
```

then you can insert values into it:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT IdentityTable ON 

INSERT IdentityTable(TheIdentity, TheValue) 
VALUES (3, 'First Row') 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT IdentityTable OFF
```

Comment: but if i dont want to add manually the value - the identity field show grow each time by 1?

Comment: @user3616125 yeah, if you don't add it manually like in my example, it will grow by 1 each time.

Comment: What do i need to not add manually? I tried to leave the identity filed empty but it didnt work - it said that there was syntax error because of ,

Comment: @user3616125 make sure the the following properties on your field are set (is Identity) property is yes and identity increment is 1 and identity seed is 1

Comment: everything is set as you said

Comment: Then if you want to manually add the identity, use my code example, if you want SQL to add it for you omit the identity field from the insert

Comment: Here is what i wrote
command.CommandText = string.Format("insert into catalog(\"ID\",\"Code\") VALUES(,18);
the ID is the identity field.
it deosnt work

Comment: try this:  command.CommandText = string.Format("insert into catalog(\"Code\") VALUES(18);

Comment: it gives me this error: Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'Catalog' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

Comment: is the id field a primary key?

Comment: Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: sorry if all of the properties are set and it's a primary key, it should increment by 1 each time.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is actually how you get the *system* to supply appropriate values in the identity column, the answer is that you just don't mention it in your insert query:

```
INSERT INTO Table (ColumnA_That_Isnt_Identity,ColumnB_That_Isnt_Identity)
VALUES (9,'abc')
```

And then the `IDENTITY` column will be assigned a value automatically.

---

If you want to know what value was assigned to this column, you can either query [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) as a separate `SELECT` or include an [`OUTPUT` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx), as here:

```
INSERT INTO Table (ColumnA_That_Isnt_Identity,ColumnB_That_Isnt_Identity)
OUTPUT inserted.ID_Column_That_Is_The_Identity
VALUES (9,'abc')
```

---

When [`IDENTITY_INSERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) is `ON`, you're telling the system "trust me, **I'll** supply an appropriate value". When it's `OFF`, you're telling the system to supply the value. Those are your two choices.

There's no means to, on the one had, set `IDENTITY_INSERT` as `ON`, and, whilst that is set, request that the system provide a value. Given that `IDENTITY_INSERT` has only a single purpose, to allow *you* to provide the values, this should never be a problem.